# Access post data from inside ajax error function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have the below javascript function that takes `POST` data and sends post request to server using `Ajax`

```
function postData(post_data) {
    console.log(post_data, "----------->"); 
    var data = post_data;
    var url = "/super/man/"
    $.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: post_data,
        dataTpe: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          debugger;
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          debugger;
          // Can we access the post_data inside this error function ?
        },
      }
    );

  };
```

So what my actual point is, because of some reason the server is sending a `500 response` and so the execution point is coming to `error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data)`, here I want to access `post_data` to display something to the user.... So can we access the `post_data` inside ajax error function above?

Comment: Why don't you just use your `post_data` variable? It's already defined for you. You can use it freely.

Comment: use your post_data variable.

Comment: Why didn't you just try it to find out ? Simply use your `data`var in the error callback function. (rename the callback argument OR the `var data` as the callback argument overrides it in its own scope)

Comment: I already checked it... It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: Don't use the variable `data`. Use `post_data`.

Comment: can you show me your main file ie "/super/man/"? 
500 error occur when syntax error there?

Comment: @Jinesh From backend, i raised a SyntaxError(in python `raise SyntaxError`) intentionally to make the javascript execution come to error block...

Comment: can you right in python just hello

Comment: What do you mean by that ? Can you please be clear ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case someone looks for a generic way to do this, here is how i did it: In case your handler functions are defined where their scope don't allow you to access some variables, you can add them to the ajax object itself in the function `beforeSend`. You can then retreive it in the ajax object by using `this`.

```js
$.ajax({
    url:'/dummyUrl',
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, plainObject){
        plainObject.originalUrl = 'myValue';
    },
    success: function (response) {
        $('#output').html(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
        $('#myValue').html(this.originalUrl);
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output">waiting result</div>
<div id="myValue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function postData(post_data) {
    console.log(post_data, "----------->"); 
    // var data = post_data; // why ?
    var url = "/super/man/"
    $.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: post_data,
        dataTpe: "json",
        success: function (response) { // pay attention to args and vars naming as it makes the code easier to read
          // use response
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
          // handle error
          console.log(post_data); // and the magic happens
        },
      }
    );

  };
```

Comment: Same error `Uncaught ReferenceError: post_data is not defined`

Comment: Can you post the complete console log ?

Comment: `VM1984:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: post_data is not defined
    at eval (eval at error (happy_rules.js:78), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at Object.error (happy_rules.js:78)
    at c (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:3)
    at k (jquery.min.js:5)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery.min.js:5)`

Comment: and the first `console.log(post_data, "----------->");` ? What does it output ?

Comment: Just an output what I need `{id: -1, name: "1", description: "",`...}

Answer (score 0):

Above this issue you were having wrong key "dataType" i have modified it. Secondly, "post_data" is in your scope you can access it without any issue.

```
    function postData(post_data) {
    console.log(post_data, "----------->"); 
    // var data = post_data; // why ?
    var url = "/super/man/"
    $.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: post_data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) { // pay attention to args and vars naming as it makes the code easier to read
          // use response
        },
        error: function ( jqXHR jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // post data is in your scope you can easily access it
          console.log(post_data); // and the magic happens
        },
      }
    );

  };
```